# How to perform multiple swipe using AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I want to perform multiple swipe when "Clicked" using `AccessibilityService`. I already tried this but it doesn't perform multiple swipe. Any help is much appreciated. It is working but only one swipe is registered.

```
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent)
    {
        final int eventType= accessibilityEvent.getEventType();
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case 1:
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                {

                        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

                        int middleYValue = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2;
                        final int leftSideOfScreen = displayMetrics.widthPixels / 4;
                        final int rightSizeOfScreen = leftSideOfScreen * 3;
                        GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
                        Path path = new Path();

                        if (accessibilityEvent.getText() != null && accessibilityEvent.getText().toString().contains("1"))
                        {
                            path.moveTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
                            path.lineTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            path.moveTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);
                            path.lineTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
                        }

                        gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));
                        gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));

                        for (int i=0;i<5;++i)
                        {
                            swipe(gestureBuilder.build());
                        }
                }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry i don't have enough reputation to add comment so i'm suggesting u here that for multiple swipe use multiple handlers. And the time in milliseconds of handler should be same as duration of swipe.

Answer (score -2):

http://jatimqq.winpublic

```
void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent)
{
    final int eventType= accessibilityEvent.getEventType();
    switch (eventType)
    {
        case 1:
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            {

                    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

                    int middleYValue = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2;
                    final int leftSideOfScreen = displayMetrics.widthPixels / 4;
                    final int rightSizeOfScreen = leftSideOfScreen * 3;
                    GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
                    Path path = new Path();

                    if (accessibilityEvent.getText() != null && accessibilityEvent.getText().toString().contains("1"))
                    {
                        path.moveTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
                        path.lineTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        path.moveTo(leftSideOfScreen, middleYValue);
                        path.lineTo(rightSizeOfScreen, middleYValue);
                    }

                    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));
                    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, 50));

                    for (int i=0;i<5;++i)
                    {
                        swipe(gestureBuilder.build());
                    }
            }
    }
}
```