# How do I swipe in a view in android native using AccessibilityEvent?

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to swipe over a specific view in screen. I have tried the option to swipe using the Point which works perfectly. But this does not fit in all situation since there are thousands of brands of mobile phone which differ in pixels due to home button or top notch area.
What I want is I want to have get exact placement of the view on Accessibility event.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420320/perform-swipe-on-screen-using-accessibilityservice or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356373/how-to-perform-multiple-swipe-using-accessibilityservice or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472985/android-set-talkback-accessibility-focus-to-a-specific-view